How to dynamically change size of grid when adding a new row in PySide6 or PyQt6?
I have a method called addNewRow which will add a new LineEdit widget into the gridLayoutWidget. I'm trying to change the size of my grid to keep all the widgets from getting squished, but all the widgets in the rows keep getting slightly squished vertically. How can I fix this?
The window created by qt designer, and the arrow points to the button that adds a new row:
GUI
After adding new rows:
GUI

from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,
    QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QWidget)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(640, 480)
        self.widget = QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setObjectName(u"widget")
        self.widget.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 631, 471))
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QWidget(self.widget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName(u"gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 293, 94))
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.label_2 = QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(u"label_2")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        self.lineEdit_2 = QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(u"lineEdit_2")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(u"lineEdit")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.label = QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)


        self.retranslateUi(Form)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.label_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Course IDS", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"+", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Course Names", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"+", None))
    # retranslateUi

from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,
    QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QWidget, QMainWindow, QStackedWidget)
import sys
from ui_settings2 import Ui_Form

class MyForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.gridLayoutWidget.setSizePolicy(
            QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.addNewRow)
        

    def addNewRow(self):
        new_line = QLineEdit("New Course")
        new_line.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        g_widget = self.ui.gridLayoutWidget
        row_count = self.ui.gridLayout.rowCount()
        self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(new_line, row_count, 0)
        self.ui.gridLayoutWidget.resize(g_widget.width(), g_widget.height() + new_line.sizeHint().height())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MyForm()

form.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())


This class inherits from the parent class which I copy pasted from the generate python code in qt designer.
I used self.gridLayoutWidget.resize() to keep the gridLayout from getting squished vertically, and the function made the squishing slightly less but it didn't fully fix the squishing problem.

Please provide a proper [mre]. Also, creating a subclass that inherits the form class alone is quite pointless. Those classes should always be used only for composition or for multiple inheritance, as explained in the official guidelines about using Designer.

thanks for the reply, changed the code and edited my explanation.

Sorry but that's not reproducible, since you're not providing the code of Ui_Form, and we cannot make guesses about the generic layout and settings that the UI could have. Please provide a proper MRE as requested.

sorry, added the Ui_form class and made it reproducible

You've just added a layout to an inner widget (widget), that widget itself is not in a layout. The top level widget (the window) must have a layout, and any further container should too. Check the object inspector, every time you see a small red "forbidden" icon near a widget, it means that it doesn't have any layout, so it won't adapt its contents to the parent (or the window). Since the UI is simple, you'll be better by recreating it from scratch, add the line edits and buttons, then right click on an empty area and select "lay out in a grid" from the layout sub menu.

Thank you for the help, I’ll try doing what you said
